# Django unable to encrypt user password info and unable to retrieve userprofile information

Tags: python, django, user-registration

I have a web application which has user registration and update user profile. I am using password hashers.

This is my models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

This is my forms.py

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(
        max_length=254,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control input-lg",'placeholder': 'username'}),
    )
    email = forms.CharField(
        max_length=254,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control input-lg",'placeholder': 'email'}),
    )
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-control input-lg",'placeholder': 'password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': "form-control input-lg",'placeholder': 'confirm password'}),label="Confirm password")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password','password2')

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    website = forms.URLField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control input-lg",'placeholder': 'website'}))
   picture=form.Imagefield
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('website', 'picture')
```

This is my views.py update and register

```
def register(request):

registered = False


if request.method == 'POST':

    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST)

    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

        user = user_form.save()

        user.set_password(user.password)
        user.save()

        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user

        if 'picture' in request.FILES:
            profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']

        profile.save()

        registered = True

    else:
        print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors

else:
    user_form = UserForm()
    profile_form = UserProfileForm()

return render(request,
        'Survey/register.html',
        {'user_form': user_form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'registered': registered} )

@login_required
def update(request):
updated = False
user = request.user
profile=request.userprofile
# If it's a HTTP POST, we're interested in processing form data.
if request.method == 'POST':

    user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST,instance=user)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm(data=request.POST,instance=profile)

    if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

        user = user_form.save()

        u = User.objects.get(username=user.username)
        u.set_password(user.password)
        u.save()

        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user

        if 'picture' in request.FILES:
            profile.picture = request.FILES['picture']

        profile.save()

        update = True

    else:
        print user_form.errors, profile_form.errors

else:
    user_form = UserForm(instance=user)
    profile_form = UserProfileForm()

return render(request,
        'Survey/update_profile.html.html',
        {'user_form': user_form,'profile_form': profile_form,'updated': updated} )
```

I have two problems with this

1. I am able to retrieve the user information but not user profile information
2. The password field I updated is stored without hashing (during registration the password is stored with hashing) so I am unable to login with the new password as authentication fails

Any help?

Comment: The problem is within your update view. You "double hash" the password in these lines:
        `u = User.objects.get(username=user.username)
        u.set_password(user.password)
        u.save()`

Comment: Thanks I got that part